# The joint PDF of f(x,y)=1/16 for 0 ≤ x, y ≤ 4. What is the conditional PDF of Y = 1?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

The given solution :

[Solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1cue.png)

I find it really counter-intuitive that how can the probability that random variable take the value 1 = 1/4. I thought in continuous random variable, the PDF output the density and that is why we take the area. And how is the joint PDF of x and y when y = 1 is still 1/16.

Doesn't it change once we assign the value 1 to the random variable Y ?

Can someone please explain.

Comment: The marginal wrt y is obtained by integrating the joint pdf wrt the variable x over the space of the joint pdf. Suggest you review "mmarginal density".

Comment: $p(x, y)=1/16$ is JOINT probability density, it's a tool to calculate marginal probability (of either X or Y). when you fix $Y$ then you're left with only one random variable X, Y no longer random any more. So you can no longer say anything random about $Y$ and can only calcilating PDF of what's left which is random, i.e., X, by intergrating over X.

Comment: The joint pdf is $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=1/16$ when $0\leq x\leq 4$ and $0\leq y\leq 4$. Because  $0\leq 1\leq 4$, then clearly $f_{X,Y}(x,1)=1/16$ when $0\leq x\leq 4$.  That is: the joint pdf is constant for all $y$ not less than $0$ and not greater than $4$, so it is that constant for $y$ equal to $1$.

Comment: In my last comment, I forget to mention that you can also bound $Y$ to an interval, for example, $Y\in [2, 4]$.

Answer (score 1):

> how is the joint PDF of x and y when y = 1 is still 1/16.

When you fix $Y=1$ then you can't simply use joint PDF (a function of $x$ and $y$) and say that the joint PDF of x and y when y=1 is still 16. Because Y is now known, it's no longer random so it's not  a function of $x$ and $y$ any more.

Instead you need to rely on the following definition of $f_{XY}(x, y)$ or just $f(x, y)$:

$$
P\{X\in A,Y\in B\} = \int_{B}^{}\int_{A}^{}f(x,y)dx dy
$$

Or equivalently:

$$
f(x, y)= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}F(x,y)
$$

Where (suppose $X\in\mathbb{R}, Y\in \mathbb{R}$): $F(x,y)=P\{X\in (-\infty, x], Y\in (-\infty, y] \}$ is the joint cumulative probability distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

So if you substitute $Y=1$ what you get is:

$$
f(x, 1)= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}F(x,y)|_{y=1},
$$

a function of single variable $x$ that is often used to calculate the PDF of $X$ conditioned on $Y$ (as you see in the solution).

> Doesn't it change once we assign the value 1 to the random variable Y?

No it doesn't because $f(x, y)$ is defined to behave as such, though it may change if, for example, $f(x, y)=2+y$ (of course you should have different bounds for $X$ and $Y$ for it to be a valid joint PDF).